# Failed to connect to database. Not a valid file name (ArcMap, personal geodatabase)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, personal-geodatabase

Windows 10, ArcMap 10.8, local parent directory, personal geodatabase

I tried solutions suggested for this problem but they don't work. I have several similar ArcMap projects for different regions. In some projects layers are not accessible and when I try to change the data source an error pops up: "Failed to connect to database. An underlying database error occurred. Not a valid file name".

I tried changing the database file name, tried to change the directory of the file, tried to run AccessDatabaseEngine but nothing works. Some solutions suggested deleting the file lock but I don't have it in the file directory. When I open the DB in Access I can see the attributes, it doesn't suggest me to fix the DB (I don't have licensed Office but other ArcMap projects still work).

Those projects that DO work are dated this year and those that DON'T are dated last year so I thought there could be a compatibility problem. Unfortunately, because I have not created those projects I don't know which ArcGIS version was used.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain the name of the Access database for which the error "Not a valid file name" is generated.

Comment: any special characters in the path to the file ?

Comment: what if you add the fc as a new layer in you mxd ?

Comment: if personal geodatabase (older than 10.8) you need to upgrade them (take a backup first) then use https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/geodatabase-upgrades.htm

Comment: @Mapperz thanks for the response but this didn't help unfortunately. I've got an error while running "Upgrade geodatabase": ERROR 001056 The input is not a valid Geodatabase.
Wierd thing. Just tried to add this db to another map project and it worked when I added separate fcs as separate layers. So it looks like a problem with the map project and not with the db

Comment: @radouxju the only special character is underscore, plus there's a space in my user name. Couldn't add it as new FC, error as well.

Comment: just to be sure, try to put it in a directory without space, and to open it in a new project. The issue seems to be with your mdb, not with your mxd.

Comment: arcgis 10.8 is the latest, so it should open older versions without problem

Comment: @radouxju it does open it in a different project regardless of the presence of space in the directory. The initial project though doesn't open the db whether I have space in the directory or not. I guess since I can open it in a different project, I could export it as shp and import it where I need. Thanks

Comment: if it comes from mxd, try 1) to delete the normal.mxt file or 2) to use mxddoctor. But this is without guarantees. Exporting as shp is a good idea, but you could also try exporting in another mdb (shp could alter some field names, etc)